# How do I install gecko driver and firefox on my docker image apache/airflow:2.1.4

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, airflow

I am trying to use Selenium on one of my airflow tasks. I have airflow running on `apache/airflow:2.1.4` docker image.

I get the following error when I use selenium in my airflow task (since I'm missing firefox)
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'firefox': 'firefox'`

How would I go about adding geckodriver and firefox to the airflow image?

I have my `docker-compose` build the following `Dockerfile` for airflow,

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.4
WORKDIR /python_dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`apache/airflow:2.1.4` is based on debian, so you just need to use `apt-get install firefox-esr` to get `firefox command`, while download pre-built binary from [geckodriver github](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/) to install geckodriver.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.4

USER root
RUN apt-get update                             \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates curl firefox-esr           \
 && rm -fr /var/lib/apt/lists/*                \
 && curl -L https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz | tar xz -C /usr/local/bin \
 && apt-get purge -y ca-certificates curl
USER airflow
```

**Verify:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=which abc:1 firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=which abc:1 geckodriver
/usr/local/bin/geckodriver
```